# Powershell -trying to fetch the description field of bulk users

Tags: powershell

```
$s=[ADSI]"LDAP://CN=PF Migrated - Inbox804923@aecom.com,OU=ContactObjects,OU=Exchange,DC=na,DC=aecomnet,DC=com"
$s.description
```

Folder path: `\ANZ\Townsville\Projects\606x\60608278_NW Traffic & Safety Plan\Inbox`

In the above scenario $s.description gives me the description but in below loop $contact gives correct info but  $contact.description shows nothing

```
foreach($u in $pf)
{

$contact= -join ('[ADSI]"LDAP://' + "$($u.Distinguishedname)" + '"')
$contact.description

}
```

Comment: your `$contact` line does not seem to be calling the `adsi` stuff ... it seems to be just building a string - and string objects don't have a `.Description` property. [*grin*]

Comment: Thank you.so how can call it after building the string

Comment: build the string - the part after the `[ADSI] - 1st and then apply the `[ADSI]` type accelerator to the string.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the format of your working command, no quotes around the type accelerator `[ADSI]` Then just apply that to your loop.

```
foreach($u in $pf)
{
    $contact= [ADSI]"LDAP://$($u.Distinguishedname)"
    $contact.description
}
```

Answer (score 0):

foreach($u in $pf){$u.name;[ADSI]"LDAP://$($u.distinguishedname)"}
works ! thanks everybody for helping me :)